# Get checked checkbox values in an array on form submit

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get all the values of checkboxes and alert them that are checked on form submit,

Here is what I have tried so far:

**HTML**

```
<form id="calform">
<input type="checkbox" value="one_name" />
<input type="checkbox" value="one_name1"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="one_name2"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**jQuery Script**

```
      $("#calform").submit(function(e){

    // array that will store all the values for checked ones
    var allVals = [];

    $('input[type="checkbox"] :checked').each(function() {

    // looping through each checkbox and storing values in array for checked ones.
    allVals.push($(this).val());

    });

    alert(allVals);

    e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Here it is on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d893C/)

Alert box shows up empty on form submit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')`, note the space was removed between `input[type="checkbox"]` and the pseudo class `:checked`:

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Svg4x/)

```
 $("#calform").submit(function (e) {

     var allVals = [];

     $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
      //     removed the space ^

         allVals.push($(this).val());
     });
     alert(allVals);

     e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

don't use descendant selector `input[type="checkbox"]:checked` for input and :checked selectors - no space between them

```
var allVals = [];
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
    // looping through each checkbox and storing values in array for checked ones.
    allVals.push($(this).val());
});
```

---

but it will easier to use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var allVals = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function () {
    return this.value
}).get();
```

Answer (score 2):

There should not be any space here `[type="checkbox"]:checked`.

Change

```
$('input[type="checkbox"] :checked').each(function() {
```

to

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/d893C/1/)